# How can you post a status to Facebook without requiring API login?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to set up a web tool with the ability to share a message on Twitter and Facebook, but I'm not sure how to make a post to Facebook directly. I'd like an interface something like Twitter's standard tweet button, or even just a link directly into Facebook with the status message field pre-populated, but I don't want to require anyone to authorize the app with Facebook if I can help it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Afaik, there is no way to link to FB with the status field pre-filled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of July 12th `message` parameter is ignored: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

So there is no way to pre-fill the message text