# How can i post stories to facebook page without login to the account in php?

Tags: php, facebook

```
         <?php
          session_start();

         $appid = 'xxxxxxxx'; //Application ID
        $appsec = 'xxxxx'; // Application secret
    $redirectUrl = 'http://test/tester/'; //Facebook redirects back to this page
    $permissions = 'publish_stream,offline_access,read_stream,manage_pages'; // Permissions we will need
    $access_token = '';


    if(isset($_POST['FacebookPageID']) && strlen($_POST['FacebookPageID'])>10)
    {

$_SESSION['FacebookPageID']=$_POST['FacebookPageID'];
$_SESSION['FacebookMessage']=$_POST['FacebookMessage'];
 $_SESSION['Facebooktitle']=$_POST['Facebooktitle'];
 // $_SESSION['image']=$_POST['image'];
}

if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['FacebookPageID']) || strlen($_SESSION['FacebookPageID'])<5)
{
 session_destroy();
die("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;URL=".$redirectUrl."\" />");
}
else
{

if(!isset($_GET["code"]))
{

     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));

     $RedirectToFacebook = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$appid;
        $RedirectToFacebook .="&redirect_uri=".urlencode($redirectUrl.'process.php');
     $RedirectToFacebook .="&state=".$_SESSION['state'];


  die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">top.location.href='" . $RedirectToFacebook . "';</script>
  <noscript><a href='".$RedirectToFacebook."'>Needs Permissioins</a></noscript>");
}
else
{

############## Facebook Page ID ############
$facebookPageID = $_SESSION['FacebookPageID'];
//$target_path   = $_SESSION['image'];

 ############## Wall Message ############
$facebookMessage = (empty($_SESSION['FacebookMessage']) || strlen($_SESSION['FacebookMessage'])<5)?"Nice Facebook Wall Posting Script!":$_SESSION['FacebookMessage'];


if($_GET['state'] == $_SESSION['state'])
{
$AccessTokenUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$appid;
$AccessTokenUrl .="&redirect_uri=".urlencode($redirectUrl.'process.php');
$AccessTokenUrl .="&client_secret=".$appsec;
$AccessTokenUrl .="&code=".$_GET["code"];

 $ReturnedString = file_get_contents($AccessTokenUrl);
 $params=null;
 parse_str($ReturnedString, $params);
$OurAccessToken = $params['access_token']; //access token

 //---------------
require_once('src/facebook.php' ); //Include our facebook Php Sdk

$post_url = '/'.$facebookPageID.'/feed';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $appid,
    'secret' => $appsec,
 ));

 //the Posting Parameters
    $PostData = array(
    'message' => 'uffcaffnews.com',
 'name' => $Facebooktitle,
 'caption' => "test.fff.com",
 'link' => 'http://www.fff.com/assets/ajax-post-on-page-wall',
'description' => $facebookMessage,
    'picture' => "http://test.c/images/desc.jpg",
'access_token' =>$OurAccessToken,
'actions' => array(
array(
'name' => 'Saaraan',
'link' => 'http://www.saaraan.com'
)
 )
 );

try {

$pageID = '3xxx';
$result = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $PostData);


     if($result)
{
 session_destroy();
     echo 'Done..';
 die("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;URL=".$redirectUrl."?");
 }
}
```

i want to post stories to facebook page from my website admin without logging in to the facebook account.please help mei want to post stories to facebook page from my website admin without logging in to the facebook account.please help me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `offline_access` permission to post content to Facebook. Only the `publish_stream` permission is needed.

Even if no user login is required. Once the user authorize your app with the `publish_stream` permission, you can start posting content on his behalf *without* the need of him to login!

You may refer [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-a-message-on-the-user-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/33/).

Comment: i removed offline_access from $permissions and set "Remove offline_access permission: enabled"
in facebook apps but still i couldnt post content to facebook without login please advice me what are all the changes should i make in code

Comment: yes i have referred the link..its  askin me to login..can you please help me with the changes in code

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205602/facebook-api-how-to-post-to-own-application-wall-without-login AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267372/posting-to-facebook-page-from-facebook-application-without-login-to-facebook AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065578/how-can-you-post-a-status-to-facebook-without-requiring-api-login